What makes old questions pop up as "new" ones?
I occasionally see questions at the top of the activity list that have actually been asked, discussed, and answered some years ago.  The fine print says something like, "modified by so-and-so an hour ago" but when you look hard, none of the answers or comments seem to be new.  Why do these pop up ?

I blame random bit flips by tachyons. Your mileage may vary.

Without an example it is difficult to say for certain, but the most common reason you don't see any modification when opening the question is that someone posted an answer that was then deleted (e.g. because it was spam). Since users below 10k reputation cannot see deleted posts, you have no way to tell this has happened.

If only users with >10k reputation can see these actions, it would be nice if the questions also appeared only for them. I'm getting quite sick of these old questions clogging my feed and taking away attention from new ones.

@paulina You could make that a feature request on [meta.SE], but I suspect the SE data model will not support this, i.e. it would be unreasonably difficult to implement this.

@paulina set your feed to "newest" or even "unanswered" if you are only interested in seeing new questions.

That can happen if someone fixes a typo in the question or one of the answers, if there is an edit to an older thread it shows up at the top again.
